# Is it true that the generator of maximal ideal in $M_n(P[x])$ can be choosen to be monic?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $P$ be a finite field and $R=M_n(P[x])$ be a matrix polynomial ring.
I want to prove 
that for every  polynomial (not necessary with invertible leading term) $A(x)\in R$ such that $R\cdot A(x)$ is a **maximal left ideal** there exists a  **unique monic** polynomial $B(x)\in R$ such that
$$
R\cdot A(x) = R\cdot B(x)
$$

Crossposted  [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277529/is-it-true-that-the-generator-of-maximal-ideal-in-m-npx-can-be-choosen-to).

Comment: Did you mean $M_n(P)[x]$? Because the elements of $M_n(P[x])$ are not polynomials.

Comment: yes. But it means implicitly that this rings are isomorphic

Comment: This question belongs here, not on mathoverflow... Crossposting, in general, is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morita equivalence for matrix algebras says $M_n(P[x])-\mathrm{Mod}\cong P[x]-\mathrm{Mod}$, so there is a bijection between the maximal left ideals (which gives irreducible modules) of $M_n(P[x])$ and those of $P[x]$.

Let's see concretely how they are corresponded. 
There is a $M_n(P[x])$-$P[x]$-bimodule, the standard module $P[x]^n$, which is a projective generator for both $M_n(P[x])-\mathrm{Mod}$ and $P[x]-\mathrm{Mod}$. Then, given any $M_n(P[x])$-module $M$, we associate to it the $P[x]$ module $\mathrm{Hom}_{M_n(P[x])}(P[x]^n, M)$. Conversely given any $M_n(P[x])$-module $N$, we associate to it the $M_n(P[x])$ module $P[x]^n\otimes_{P[x]} N$.

In this way, we see in particular that the regular left-module $M_n(P[x])$ gives the free $P[x]$-module $P[x]^n$ of rank $n$ and that maximal left ideals correspondes to minimal quotients of $P[x]^n$. If $I = P[x]A(x)$ is a maximal left ideal, then $M_n(P[x])/I$ corresponds under the Morita equivalence to $P[x]/(\det A(x))$. Thus $\det A(x)$ must be a irreducible polynomial in $P[x]$.

If $B(x)\in M_n(P[x])$ is a monic polynomial, then $\det B(x)$ must be of degree divisible by $n$. We see that those maximal left ideal $I$ such that $M_n(P[x])/I$ is of dimension not divisible by $n$ cannot be generated by a single monic polynomial in $M_n(P[x])$, for example, the left ideal $M_2(P[x])\begin{pmatrix}x & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

When a monic polynomial $B(x)$ generated a maximal left ideal $I$, we know however that $B(x)$ must be the unique one that does so. To see that, if $C(x)$ is another, then $C(x) = D(x)B(x)$ for some $D(x)\in M_n(P[x])$. We see then that $\mathrm{deg} C(x) = \mathrm{deg} B(x)$, so it is clear that $D(x) = \mathrm{I}_n$.

Comment: So, as I understand from your post there exist such maximal ideals that are not generated by monic polynomials?

Comment: Yes, I don't think one can find any monic polynomial matrix which generates the left ideal $M_2(P[x])\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I also found a negative answer for my question via skew linear recurrent sequences. But your proof is better and shorter)